# assign an array to a variable changed the type?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, tags

I get this error when I assign my array to a variable:

> 'krsort()` expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Here's my code:

```
    if ( !in_array( $controller, $bypass_controller ) ) {
        $sesscontroller = $this->CI->privileges->getcontrolleruri();
        if ( $sesscontroller && empty( $sesscontroller ) ) {
            $sesscontroller      = $this->CI->session->userdata( SESS_PREFIK . 'controllers' );
            $arrcnt              = array(
                'menu_name'  => 'Add',
                'controller' => ''
            );
            $sesscontroller[]    = $arrcnt;

        } else {
            if ( !is_null( $sesscontroller ) ) {
                krsort( $sesscontroller );
                $this->CI->session->set_userdata( array(
                    SESS_PREFIK . 'controllers' => $sesscontroller
                ) );
            }
        }
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: We can't see your data so how are we supposed to help more than the error message? I find the error message quite clear. But are you sure it's not `$controller` you want to sort? That is an array as far as I can see.

Comment: `var_dump` The value returned by `this->CI->privileges->getcontrolleruri()`. It's probably a string and not an array.

Comment: It is a string, no need to var_dump. I'm quite sure PHP is not lying

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the if - `$sesscontroller && empty( $sesscontroller )` looks a bit odd.

Comment: In krsort function only pass array arguments so in your arguments variable value is not array so this give error

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. try to solve hope is work

```
<?php
if ( !in_array( $controller, $bypass_controller ) ) {
    $sesscontroller = $this->CI->privileges->getcontrolleruri();
    if ( $sesscontroller && empty( $sesscontroller ) ) {
        $sesscontroller      = $this->CI->session->userdata( SESS_PREFIK . 'controllers' );
        $arrcnt              = array(
            'menu_name'  => 'Add',
            'controller' => ''
        );
        $sesscontroller[]    = $arrcnt;

        if ( !is_null( $sesscontroller ) ) {
            krsort( $sesscontroller );
            $this->CI->session->set_userdata( array(
                SESS_PREFIK . 'controllers' => $sesscontroller
            ) );
        }

    } else {
        // This ELSE part is this line 
        // $sesscontroller = $this->CI->privileges->getcontrolleruri();
        //echo $sesscontroller;
    }
}
?>
```